# Anybody knows a "good" framework for games in the HTML5 canvas? (see requirements)

Tags: canvas, frameworks

I would need a framework for HTML5 and canvas that:

- Free and opensource
- Write in javascript (no GWT, no java, no coffescript, no other languages) (as I will use node.js on the server and maybe will be integrated with a qooxdoo app)
- Drag and drop large images (3000x2000px)
- Zoom in and out
- Allows me some UI: label, buttons, textField, textArea, scroller
- Animation framework, just simple displacement.
- Layers

A plus might be:

- Uses objects for each drawn object and a OOP approach;
- Supports modular components (MVC structure)

Thanks,

Comment: I don't think there are any 1-framework-solutions that implements all of those different aspects of game-dev and yet uses only javascript. You want built-in zooming, UI (AWT components), animation, and layering functionality; and as if not enough, it should be intended for modular implementation and have an OO approach? Oh yea, lets not forget it must be free on top of that! --- I mean...No offence but...Do you want it to serve your coffee too? While it does "all" the job for you, that is. --- Other features are a little more likely, but zoom makes it a hard-find, as it's very game-dependant.

Comment: zoom: it would help me if it would had some built in feature that allows to enlarge an image in canvas. I don't think this is so special as many of them allow you to import an image and scale it, which is zooming in and out.

Answer (score 2):

ImpactJS should be a right option for your. (Not sure about DnD for large images).

http://impactjs.com/

Comment: I would like to be free, not paid. (my fault as I didn't specified in the question) but thanks anyway

Comment: @Totty, Even tho you want a free one i would still recommend impactjs because it comes with a library that turns it into a native iOS application.  i know you can use PhoneGap to do the same, but for games that require a high smooth frame rate ImpactJS wins almost all the time.  And it's only like $100 as of this post.

Answer (score 2):

I would endorse CraftyJS. It has most of the features you're looking for except the macro images and UI classes. It's a good implementation of the Entity/Component design pattern. Check it out if you're interested. http://craftyjs.com